# SDL and binding buffers

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, sdl

so I've been trying to understand SDL interface and attach my OpenGL and freeglut test program to it - cleaning it from glut references. Most problematic part became when I tried to attach shaders - everything was compiling, but I keep getting Segmentation fault error. The cleaned version of program is:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_GLContext *context;
GLuint vao;

SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
SDL_CreateWindow("cookie", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
512, 512, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
cout<<"Hi! It's my first instance"<<endl;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
cout<<"And it's my second - i can't reach here"<<endl;
}
```

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04, Radeon 8somethingsomething card (if it does really matter). The command i use to compile is:

```
g++ main.cpp -lGL -lGLEW -lSDL2
```

PS. Sorry for being iostream newbie, I started programming from c++.

Comment: A "Radeon 8somethingsomething" card is not going to support OpenGL 3.0, by the way (which is where `glGenVertexArrays` comes from). The 9xxx series doesn't technically support everything required by GL 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

You never assign a value to `window`. When SDL dereferences the pointer passed to `SDL_GL_CreateContext` it crashes, because there's no valid pointer value in `window`.

#### Update (fixed code)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );

    SDL_Window * const window = SDL_CreateWindow(
       "cookie",
       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
       512, 512,
       SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);        
    if( !window ) {
        cerr << "creating window failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_GLContext * const context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if( !context ) {
        cerr << "creating OpenGL context failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
/* ... */
```

#### Update 2

what @keltar wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26645107/524368

Comment: Nah, still segmentation fault. But thanks for advice.

Comment: @CheshireCat: It's not so much the error check, but that you create a window and then… you loose-discard the pointer to the Window object created by SDL. The variable `window` never sees a valid value and what you pass to `SDL_GL_CreateContext` is worse than garbage. You're invoking language undefined behavior and the compiler would be in its full right to create a program binary, that for example when executed wipes anything from your harddisk it can find.

Comment: @CheshireCat: keltar also spotted something important. Read his answer. Anyway you really should check errors and keep the results of function calls around.

Answer (score 3):

`glGenVertexArrays` is extension function. You've included `glew.h`, which handles extensions - but you haven't initialised it. `glewInit` have to be called after creating GL context (and check its return value).

Also a bit of advice - segmentation fault isn't some weird magic you should be scared of and google what the hell happened. It is very well defined. If you'll run your program in debugger, you'll see where exactly it crashed and why (because `glGenVertexArrays` function is called, but value of this function pointer is NULL). If you using native language like C, you'll see that a lot, so some time spent on learning how to use debugger (if you don't know that already) will save you (and others, mind you) a lot of time later.